# Help with install - persistent error while loading shared libraries - Novice user

Tags: virtualbox

I am a novice Ubuntu user and I can't seem to figure this out.

I am trying to install this program called treePL
https://github.com/blackrim/treePL/wiki/Installation

Seems simple, right?

I got the files from GitHub

I followed the directions on the site above to install the two dependencies
When I try to run the program, I get:
tayne@tayne-VirtualBox:~/treePL/src$ sudo treePL arbtree.cppr8s
treePL: error while loading shared libraries: libadolc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I added `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64` to the bottom of my ~/.bashrc file but it doesn't seem to work. When I navigate to lib64 I see the file that is supposed to be there is actually there.

I have tried restarting both the machine and the terminal.

I need help, somewhat spelled out to me. I don't "get" this file architecture yet and it's frustrating me. It may have someone to do with where this stuff is installed and this weird pathing, but the way this works confuses me and I don't understand it.

Thanks so much in advance. Please let me know if there is any more information needed.

Edit - The dependancies seem to be installed. The file is actually in /usr/lib64

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the package `libadolc2` (the missing library `libadolc.so.2` is a part of it)

```
sudo apt-get install libadolc2
```

The correct place should be

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Comment: Here is what comes out when I try that:
`tayne@tayne-VirtualBox:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ sudo apt-get install libadolc2Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libadolc2 is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm3.4
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 167 not upgraded.`

Comment: Any reasons for 167 not upgraded packages?

Comment: My last Linux program took 1600 hours + to run so I haven't updated anything in a while.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by running the executable with
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/ADOL-C-2.5.2/ADOL-C/.libs/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./treePL`